# Given oauth_app resource not found - Magic.Link

Tags: react-native, authentication, oauth-2.0, password-less

I tries to integrate magic link social authentication to my React Native Mobile app and it always gives error ***Given oauth_app resource not found*** as in the attached file.

I use the code as described in the documentation and they're as follows,

```
 const MagicElement = new Magic('pk_test_***********', {
  extensions: [new OAuthExtension()],
});

 try {
      const result = await MagicElement.oauth.loginWithPopup({
        provider: 'apple' /* 'google', 'facebook', 'apple', or 'github' */,
        redirectURI: 'testapp://demo/your/oauth/callback',
      });
      console.log('result', result)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error)
    }
  }
```

https://docs.magic.link/client-sdk/web/social-login

[image]

Appreciate if anyone can help to solve this issue.

Comment: I didn't enable the social authentication in the magic link dashboard. It was my bad. 
now it works

Answer (score 0):

Be careful what parameters you are passing to `loginWithPopup` etc. An easy step to take if you encounter this screen is to look at the network tab filtered on "document" type.

In my case `[object%20Object]` in the request URL was a giveway:

```
https://auth.magic.link/v1/oauth2/[object%20Object]/start?magic_api_key=...
```

After fixing the parameters the URL became something like

```
https://auth.magic.link/v1/oauth2/google/start?magic_api_key=...
```

and the error went away.